# How do I direct my openshift website to a gandi.net domain name I bought? I tried, but it's not working?

Tags: web, dns, openshift, redhat, cname

Okay so I created a web app and am hosting it on openshift. Right now, they just gave me a CNAME something like myapp-someappname.rhcloud.com. So they told me to use that CNAME to redirect to my domain.

Now on GANDI I bought a .com domain. Another thing is, I didn't realize there's much of a difference between www.website.com and just website.com, so the one I bought was just website.com. Now I have no idea how to redirect both of them to the www one.

For the CNAME I entered in gandi in expert mode www 10800 myapp-someappname.rhcloud.com. (with the dot at the end).

I woke up this morning, it's still not working. Also, when I go to www.website.com (Btw, website.com isn't my website, I'm just saying as an example) it just says app not found on server. When I go to just website.com, it actually takes me to gandi and says that the owner parked there or something.

So, what's the difference, and why does it say that?

How do I just SIMPLY get my website to work? I hosted it on openshift, have the CNAME, and at gandi I bought a .com domain with NO www in the front, so I don't know much about that. How do I just simply get this to work? I am so frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022324/how-to-setup-dns-for-an-apex-domain-no-www-pointing-to-a-heroku-app) regarding Heroku instead of Openshift, but you might easily be lost in the detailed configuration.

To simplify things, I'd recommend using Cloudflare, a Content Delivery Network, which is what I use.

Follow these steps to set it up: [How to Use a CDN with Your OpenShift Application](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-use-a-cdn-with-your-openshift-application/)