# network solutions to heroku non-www redirection to www domain

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, http-redirect, no-www

This is a very specific question I have regarding redirection of a domain on network solutions to a webapp hosted on heroku. I have already set up so that in CNAME Records, Allias www refers to hostname in heroku. The question is, currently if I type my web address without www it does not render my page. Could anyone help me please? I have tried very hard to figure this out. Hope this post will help others in the future as well.

[image: CNAME Redirection screenshot. does not work without www alias]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a non-www domain with heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015322/how-to-use-a-non-www-domain-with-heroku)

Comment: did you manage to solve it? am also using networksolutions with heroku and not able to get the apex domain to point to my app.

Comment: nope, I could not get any constructive advise. I hope someone can figure it out because I am trying to find out for so long!!!

Comment: check out the my solution, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 14):

**Network Solutions pointing yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com. Here's how.**

Within Account Manager, select My Domain Names

```
Select the domain name that you want to manage
```

In the green box, select Change Where Domain Points

```
Select Advanced DNS, then Continue
```

First, edit the A Records by selecting Edit A Records

```
For the "@ none" enter the following IP address 205.178.189.129, 
clear (delete) the records for the "www" and "* (All others)", 
then select Continue.
Sometimes this takes a few moments for the first step to take effect.
```

Second, edit the Host Aliases (CNAME records) by selecting Edit CNAME Records

> Enter "www" in the Alias column
>
> Leave TTL set to 7200 but on the same line, enter the name servers
>   provided by the blogging service in the Other Host section [ IE FOLLOW
>   THE HEROKU INSTRUCTIONS NOW www --> yourapp.herokuapp.com (Cedar
>   Stack) ]

Select Continue

Now wait and check the domain(s) with the following terminal command:

host domain.com
host www.domain.com

Comment: For everyone wondering, that IP address is an in house IP address that reroutes the Apex domain to a www domain from what Network Solutions says.

Comment: Does anyone know if this still works? I spoke to a rep at Network Solutions and they said this IP (noted above) is old and may or may not work. They said to "give it a try", but nothing more than that. I'm a little hesitant to "give it a try".

Comment: I manage several sites parked at Network Solutions and this still works.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working any more. At least not for me. My www.domain.com goes to Heroku correctly, but my naked (apex) domain does not. I have now switched over to using Google Apps to redirect my apex domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693394/using-email-w-heroku-and-cname/20115583#20115583

Comment: I just checked my sites using this solution and they are still forwarding. Are your settings correct?

Comment: It is still working, just put 205.178.189.129 in the browser and it will redirect to www. I made the A record 205.178.189.129 and CNAME to heroku and worked like a charm, thank you :)

Comment: this is no longer working http://205.178.189.129/ does not respond - anyone figured out a solution that isn't moving DNS providers?

Comment: It works with non-ssl, but doesn't do anything for SSL. If you try hitting https://205.178.189.129 it just hangs.

Answer (score 3):

If in the event, while editing the C-name records you receive this error:

```
An A record already exists for the entered Alias
```

Log out, and log back in.

This was the solution provided by Network Solutions customer support which worked for me in addition to @railrailrail's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward your apex domain to your `www` subdomain. Explained in more detail here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041655/95741

Comment: It does not appear that network solutions allows you to redirect (forwarding) to the same domain, even though it's had a subdomain appended.

Comment: it does at least to the www subdomain, please see the answer above, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

As the Network Solutions 205.178.189.129 reroute trick does not appear to be working any more, you will have to look for a third party to redirect your apex domain.

Here are a few options:

- DNSimple http://blog.dnsimple.com/2011/11/introducing-alias-record/
- DNS Made Easy http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/aname-records/
- If you are using Google Apps for your email you can let Google Apps redirect the apex domain. [Using email w/ Heroku and CNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693394/using-email-w-heroku-and-cname/20115583#20115583)
- If you have a webserver available, you can do a custom redirect using [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/500866/nginx-redirecting-only-www-subdomain-to-main-domain), [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www) or your favorite webserver.

Comment: It is working, I put it to apex record 205.178.189.129 and it worked like a charm.